# Get error cells by GetCellValue<eErrorType> or a with a different approach

Tags: c#, epplus

formulas in excel can return different errors e.g. #div/0
But how to check a cell

`package.Workbook.Worksheets["a"].Cells["g2"].GetCellValue<eErrorType>();`
will return the error type if an error exists but will crash if the formula of the cell will not produce an error. As far as I can see, the enum of eErrorType does not contain a member like NoError :-(

I would like to use something like that:

`var badCells = package.Workbook.Worksheets["a"].Cells.All(f => f.GetCellValue<eErrorType>()!???`

Any other approach welcome

tx
Perry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need to test by type like this:

```
var workbook = package.Workbook;
var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
foreach (var cell in worksheet.Cells)
{
    var x = cell.GetCellValue<object>();
    switch (x)
    {
        case double d:
            Console.WriteLine($"{cell.Address} is double: {d}");
            break;
        case ExcelErrorValue error:
            Console.WriteLine($"{cell.Address} with formula '{cell.Formula}' is error: {error.Type}");
            break;
    }
}
```

Assuming you have a sheet like:
[image]

Which give this as the output:

```
A1 is double: 1
B1 is double: 0
C1 with formula 'A1/B1' is error: Div0
```

---

**RESPONSE TO COMMENTS:**

A `foreach` would probably be more efficient since you can perform any other needed tasks inside of it but this is how to do it via LINQ:

```
var errorCells = worksheet
    .Cells
    .Where(c => c.GetCellValue<object>() is ExcelErrorValue)
    .ToList();

Console.WriteLine($"Number of error cells: {errorCells.Count}"); // Prints "1"
```

Comment: Thank you but iterating through the cells is not the goal. In Excel, for example, you have SpecialCells to determine certain cells from a range, for example cells with Error.

I think I will still find a way.

Comment: @Perry41578 Based on your question, iterating through the cells is exactly what you are looking to do with `.Cells.All...`.  LINQ is not doing any magic there, it will simply go through each cell one by one similar to the `foreach` I pasted.  The console logging I have is just demonstrative, you can do anything you like inside of it like, say, add to a collection.  For a more compact code set, I added a LINQ call to my answer.  If that is still not what you want, you may want to add more details to your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm Looking for methods to reproduce Excels Specialcells Finding first all Formulas than looking for # hopefully makes it faster. But I have to test this. I do not like to iterate to all cells if not neccessary. But one could also first get the formula cells and then use your first answer. But you put me on the right track! Thanks again! `List<ExcelRangeBase> allBadFormulas = dataSheet.Cells.Where(f => f.Formula.Length > 0 && f.Value.ToString().StartsWith("#") && f.GetCellValue<object>() is ExcelErrorValue).ToList();`

Comment: @Perry41578  Glad it helpd.  Ya, unfortunately, EPPlus does not have the concept of `SpecialCells`, AFAIK.  I think your approach is the best option.

Answer (score 1):

After I have now tested a few variants, I am once again surprised. All variants are incredibly fast and the iteration through all cells is even the fastest with a good relation of formulas to values but we are talking about milliseconds.
Test with 20000 values and 10000 formulas and 3 errors.
(all less than 80 ms)

But if you have several operations on formula cells, it is certainly worthwhile to build up a range for them first.

Thanks again to Ernie S

Enclosed my small tests, if someone wants to rebuild these:

```
private int ByLinq0(ExcelWorksheet dataSheet)
{
// using Ernie S' code
int counter = 0;
 foreach (var cell in dataSheet.Cells)
{
 var x = cell.GetCellValue<object>();
 switch (x)
 { case ExcelErrorValue error:
 counter += 1;
 break;
 }
}
return counter;
}
private int ByLinq1(ExcelWorksheet dataSheet)
{
List<ExcelRangeBase> allBadFormulas = dataSheet.Cells.Where(f => f.Formula.Length > 0 && f.Value.ToString().StartsWith("#") && f.GetCellValue<object>() is ExcelErrorValue).ToList();
 return allBadFormulas.Count;
}
private int ByLinq2(ExcelWorksheet dataSheet)
{
List<ExcelRangeBase> allBadFormulas = dataSheet.Cells.Where(f => f.Formula.Length > 0 && f.GetCellValue<object>() is ExcelErrorValue).ToList();
 return allBadFormulas.Count;
}
private int ByLinq3(ExcelWorksheet dataSheet)
{
List<ExcelRangeBase> formulas = dataSheet.Cells.Where(f => f.Formula.Length > 0).ToList();
int counter = 0;
 foreach (var cell in formulas)
{
 var x = cell.GetCellValue<object>();
 switch (x)
 {

 case ExcelErrorValue error:
 counter += 1;
 break;
 }
}
return counter;
}
```